I'm encountering a puzzling issue in my C program while working with dynamic memory allocation using realloc()
I'm encountering an issue while reading an file that contains records with length indicators and fields separated by '|'. In this program, I'm reading information about the quantity and price of a product and summing them up. However, when I attempt to use realloc() for my buffer variable, I encounter unexpected behavior. Strangely, the result I'm expecting is 118.239998, but when I use realloc(), the result becomes 118.275002. Surprisingly, when I use free(buffer) and then allocate memory again using malloc() for the buffer, I get the correct result.
This is the file
The first byte serves as a length indicator, and both '\n'(10 in decimal) and 'NL'(13 in decimal) also serve as indicators.
OUTPUT WITH FREE + MALLOC
OUTPUT WITH REALLOC
here is my code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *buffer, *produto;
    int tamRegistro, quantidade;                                                
    float preco, total = 0;
    FILE* arquivo;
  
    arquivo = fopen("compras.txt", "r");

    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        printf("Erro ao abrir o arquivo\n");
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }
    //take the first length indicator 
    tamRegistro =fgetc(arquivo);
    buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * tamRegistro);
  
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        printf("Falha ao alocar  memoria\n");
        exit(1);
    }
   
    while (fread(buffer, tamRegistro, 1, arquivo) == 1) {
        //separate fields
        printf("LENGTH:%d-", tamRegistro);
        produto = strtok(buffer, "|");
        printf("%s-", produto);         
        quantidade = atoi(strtok(NULL, "|"));
        printf("%d-", quantidade);
        preco = atof(strtok(NULL, "|"));
        printf("%f-\n", preco);
    
        total += (preco * quantidade);
        //take next length indicator
        tamRegistro = fgetc(arquivo);
        *buffer=(char*)realloc(buffer,sizeof(char)*(tamRegistro));  
    }
    
    free(buffer)
    fclose(arquivo);
    printf("%f\n",total);
  
    return 0;
}


Looks more like c than c++.

Tag only the langauage in which the code is written in. C and C++ are different languages.

tamRegistro =fgetc(arquivo);? That makes no sense. What is the very first character of the file? Please [edit] your question to show a small example of the file you try to read.

And don't post images of text. Copy-paste text as text into your questions.

Both of your output examples were text on your computer so they should be text in the question. If you are using a compiler that supports AddressSanitizer add -fsanitize=address,undefined to your compile command and see what happens. Whenever I see strtok without a check if the pointer returned is valid before use it makes me sad. I'd expect you could probably do away with the dynamic allocation altogether and just make an array large enough for the largest record on the stack and reuse it.

On a couple of different notes, in C you should not cast the result of malloc (or realloc). Or really any function that returns a void * pointer. Also, if realloc fail it will return a null pointer, but leave the original memory alone. If you assign back to the original pointer, that will make you loose the original memory and you'll have a memory leak. Always use temporary variables with realloc.

You provided no input data, so we can't check your code. But I think your input file is a text file. When you read length indicator with fgetc, its return value is not what you think. For example if length indicator is 5, you read 53 using fgetc. Since 53 is ASCII code value of 5. You must change tamRegistro = fgetc(arquivo); to tamRegistro = fgetc(arquivo) - '0' at least. This bug not led to wrong results, since you allocate mote than you want!

The use of fgetc() to read tamRegistro, then print its value with %d showing values 10 to 17 indicates this byte is "binary" data. Then, magically, there are more bytes that appear to be handled as a (delimited) string. Conversion to float, and then printing, erases any hope... Without more information, this question is unanswerable. Voting to close. Even the OP's "expected value" makes no sense...

@Lucas Froes – You have to post the program with the issue, i. e. with realloc, not the one where you get the correct result.

Suggestion: Completely remove all heap allocation (and free'ing). Use char buffer[128];. Use memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer); BEFORE each load/reload of the buffer (i.e. fread()). No more worries about not having properly terminated what you think is a C string in your buffer... Give that a try. Simpler code, too.

You use strtok to break up the buffer, but that doesn't contain a string as long as it isn't terminated by a null character; so you have to allocate one more byte and store the NUL there.

There are no presumptions, but observations. You yourself realized that the length is "binary" data - but that doesn't end the OP's "data record", it rather precedes it. That the NUL isn't stored in the file is obvious from the depicted output.

It is clear that the 2nd record is stored as pao|1|7.99, since its length is 10.

Which manual do you mean?

It's hard to read an unwritten manual. Lots of viewpoints over there... indeed, and not only the point of view you describe, however valid it may be.

Check this Scroll down to: "Respond to feedback after posting" and this Scroll down to "Answer well-asked questions". In particular: "avoid trying to answer questions which... ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem." Jus' sayin' ... You go ahead and do you...

Parting shot: Perhaps the REAL problem is the OP's code that writes this file. Perhaps the OP is under the impression that NUL IS being written so the data IS being stored as a string... None of us knows for sure... Have a great weekend!

I would have said, let's give the OP more than three hours to respond, but now the closing has taken its place. - Thanks, have a great weekend, too!

This answer on Meta... I just took a second to find out what FGITW means! (IF the OP comes back to the question and edits in required information, and gets rid of linked JPGs, they can vote to have the question re-opened... Seems harsh, but those seem to be the guidelines... OP who read "How to Ask" has been warned to stay close to computer after clicking "Submit"... Enough, already... Cheers!
